# Grouping by date in pandas keeping the date column

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to calculate % of stocks above rolling mean, therefore, I need to group the data by 'Date' and want to keep the 'Date' column. Percentages are calculated correctly, however, instead of actual dates I'm getting 'NaN' values. The 'Date' column is not the data frame index.

```
def count_number_of_stocks_above_mean(data_frame):
    data_frame = data_frame.loc[data_frame['Port. Weight'] > 0]
    #counts number of stocks at given date
    target_df_count_total = data_frame.groupby('Date')['Date', 'Price above Mean'].count().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    # counts number of stocks above mean
    target_df_count_price_above_mean = data_frame.groupby('Date')['Date','Price above Mean'].sum().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    # calculates % of stocks above mean
    target_df_prct= round((target_df_count_price_above_mean/target_df_count_total),4)
    return target_df_prct
```

Below a small chunk of the data:

```
Date    Ticker  Company Name    Ending Price    Port. Weight    Mean    Price above Mean
1989-02-09  09959910    Borden Inc. 29.25   0.217751540768903   29.01875    1
1989-02-09  205212  ASARCO Incorporated 27.625  0.0580372736732209  28.808333333333334  0
1989-02-09  209399  Burlington Resources Inc.   23.125  0.0 19.054166666666667  1
1989-02-09  219546  Chrysler Corporation    14.375  0.336072750981974   13.885416666666666  1
1989-02-09  231565  Engelhard Corporation   5.92593002319336    0.0448695607192639  5.411111052831014   1
1989-02-09  231752  ENSERCH Corporation 21.375  0.0689363878969973  19.775  1
1989-02-09  236630  General Signal Corporation  25.1875 0.0481599834119684  24.527083333333334  1
1989-02-09  247236  Jefferson-Pilot Corporation 6.51851987838745    0.0622519269932311  6.306173038482666   1
1989-02-09  247680  Johnson Controls, Inc.  2.98957991600037    0.0708125041850512  3.0357636610666914  0
1989-02-09  255096  McDonnell Douglas Corporation   15.0    0.172762591836445   13.70764001210531   1
1989-02-09  262798  NCR Corporation 59.0    0.217124786375439   56.775  1
1989-02-09  268562  Salomon Inc.    26.75   0.167658888987574   26.708333333333332  1
1989-02-09  270750  PSI Resources, Inc. 13.75   0.037335682884269   13.720833333333333  1
1989-02-09  278731  Sears Roebuck & Co. 42.25   0.725775907049812   41.791666666666664  1
1989-02-09  288080  Teledyne Inc.   70.5    0.195999964491311   68.89666646321615   1
1989-02-09  292436  Upjohn Company  31.5    0.292572776505453   29.966666666666665  1
1989-02-09  3614B   Citicorp    27.125  0.44169960825601    26.575  1
1989-02-09  37011810    General Instrument Corporation  32.0    0.0438521329982094  28.029166666666665  1
1989-02-09  45067910    ITT Corporation 54.125  0.351136727389851   52.99166666666667   1
1989-02-09  45850610    Interco Inc.    3.5 0.00673786072637269 3.154166666666667   1
1989-02-09  7448B   Security Pacific Corporation    38.625  0.219156961706361   37.05   1
1989-02-09  84610410    Sovran Financial Corporation    34.625  0.103973459146259   34.32083333333333   1
1989-02-09  AA  Aluminum Company of America 71.2968978881836    0.279191034781877   68.35312296549479   1
1989-02-09  AAL.1   Alexander & Alexander Services Inc. 23.375  0.0472567527053728  23.441666666666666  0
1989-02-09  AAMRQ   AMR Corporation 29.375  0.183440847736901   27.822916666666668  1
1989-02-09  AAPL    Apple Computer Inc. 1.36607003211975    0.241179618711581   1.4497020006179804  0
1989-02-09  ABI The Perkin-Elmer Corporation    6.0 0.0522505023153442  6.214583333333334   0
1989-02-09  ABS.1   Albertson's Inc.    10.375  0.139523284517948   9.958334986368817   1
1989-02-09  ABT Abbott Laboratories 6.1875  0.551759320307428   6.022394720713297   1
1989-02-09  ACKH    Armstrong World Industries, Inc.    36.0    0.0806460223676931  34.74166666666667   1
1989-02-09  ACV.I   Alberto-Culver Company  6.20833015441895    0.0244739725185989  5.9631937026977555  1
1989-02-09  ACY.1   American Cyanamid Co.   50.125  0.237452270838345   49.32083333333333   1
1989-02-09  ADM Archer-Daniels-Midland Company  5.47999000549316    0.208155885155713   5.261965958277385   1
1989-02-09  ADP Automatic Data Processing, Inc. 5.0 0.152894482282014   4.94531265894572    1
1989-02-09  ADSK    Autodesk, Inc.  4.0 0.03880949782187    3.7828126668930055  1
1989-02-09  AEE Union Electric Company  24.125  0.0 23.85   1
1989-02-09  AEP American Electric Power Company, Inc.   26.5    0.257303047425092   27.066666666666666  0
1989-02-09  AET Aetna Life and Casualty Company 12.5625 0.281776485499235   12.1895866394043    1
1989-02-09  AGC.1   American General Corporation    8.21875 0.200201232527231   8.004166666666666   1
1989-02-09  AGREA   American Greetings Corporation Class A  11.25   0.035879324892007   11.06875    1
1989-02-09  AHM.1   H.F. Ahmanson & Company 18.375  0.0910737143332232  17.345833333333335  1
1989-02-09  AIG American International Group, Inc.  123.470001220703    0.601267211039901   119.82483393351244  1
1989-02-09  AIT.1   Ameritech Corporation   12.9062004089355    0.69722254446526    12.284389877319347  1
1989-02-09  AL.1    Alcan Inc.  23.0    0.263589509788732   22.880560048421227  1
1989-02-09  AMD Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.    4.4375  0.0361345930657677  4.460416666666666   0
1989-02-09  AMGN    Amgen Inc.  0.8125  0.0 0.732291603088379   1
1989-02-09  AMH.1   Amdahl Corporation  19.75   0.107689221433691   20.1    0
1989-02-09  AMP.2   AMP Incorporated    23.875  0.257394412976269   23.0    1
1989-02-09  AMT.1   Acme-Cleveland Corporation  10.5    0.00331396950358141 9.908333333333333   1
1989-02-09  AMX.2   Amax Inc.   26.75   0.115624225312409   25.3625 1
1989-02-09  AN.2    Amoco Corporation   19.3125 0.995003885689492   19.239583333333332  1
1989-02-09  ANDW    Andrew Corp.    2.09876990318298    0.0107708198213365  1.9514409859975188  1
1989-02-09  ANV.1   TRINOVA Corporation 28.625  0.0490902432651675  28.204166666666666  1
1989-02-09  APD Air Products and Chemicals, Inc.    11.6875 0.128653479390695   11.278123346964517  1
1989-02-09  ARB Ceridian Corporation    50.0    0.0419296361647271  51.302083333333336  0
1989-02-09  ARC.3   Atlantic Richfield Company  42.875  0.716223838337686   41.920833333333334  1
1989-02-09  AS  Armco Inc.  11.5    0.0510253646649544  10.8875 1
1989-02-09  ASC.1   American Stores Co. 7.20312023162842    0.0996186239178344  7.315625    0
1989-02-09  ASH Ashland Oil, Inc.   34.125  0.0995478842761234  34.483333333333334  0
1989-02-09  AVATQ   National Intergroup Inc.    19.0    0.0207277690301599  19.258333333333333  0
1989-02-09  AVP Avon Products, Inc. 2.71875 0.058790918445647   2.634374666213989   1
1989-02-09  AVY Avery Dennison Corporation  11.5    0.0509572824728723  11.633333333333333  0
1989-02-09  AXP American Express Company    10.4167003631592    0.653968494064866   9.608333651224772   1
1989-02-09  AZA.1   ALZA Corporation    6.59375 0.0 6.230208333333334   1
1989-02-09  BA  Boeing Company  13.9443998336792    0.48364995543785    13.655550003051761  1
1989-02-09  BAC NationsBank Corporation 7.96875 0.159107624872378   7.25625 1
1989-02-09  BAC.Z.  BankAmerica Corporation 10.75   0.223098024073281   9.679166666666667   1
1989-02-09  BAX Baxter International Inc.   10.0625 0.251021819724081   9.516666666666667   1
1989-02-09  BBI.2   Barnett Banks Inc.  16.875  0.106395149465768   17.1125 0
1989-02-09  BC  Brunswick Corporation   18.5    0.0816369190087063  18.158333333333335  1
1989-02-09  BCO The Pittston Company    18.875  0.0355503511201737  18.045833333333334  1
1989-02-09  BCR C. R. Bard, Inc.    11.375  0.0627072141044906  11.297916666666667  1
1989-02-09  BDK Black & Decker Corporation  24.5    0.0723577238319154  23.770833333333332  1
1989-02-09  BDX Becton, Dickinson and Company   6.84375 0.104951662347605   6.637499682108561   1
1989-02-09  BEAM    American Brands, Inc.   32.0625 0.309139254049012   31.991666666666667  1
1989-02-09  BEV Beverly Enterprises Inc.    7.875   0.0213408888901008  6.916666666666667   1
1989-02-09  BF.B    Brown-Forman Corporation Class B    2.32444000244141    0.0917630551928634  2.140445637702943   1
1989-02-09  BFI Browning-Ferris Industries Inc. 30.0    0.223657008417641   28.495833333333334  1
1989-02-09  BFO.2   CPC International Inc.  13.0937995910645    0.204195447953583   13.254173278808599  0
1989-02-09  BGG Briggs & Stratton Corporation   7.0 0.0203182344760629  7.123958333333333   0
1989-02-09  BHGE    Baker Hughes Inc.   14.5    0.0867463801499602  14.741666666666667  0
1989-02-09  BHMSQ   Bethlehem Steel Corp.   27.25   0.102566672200508   25.054166666666667  1
1989-02-09  BKB.2   Bank of Boston Corporation  12.6875 0.09064500805691    12.1625 1
1989-02-09  BLL Ball Corporation    1.65625 0.0295692085114477  1.6848960002263387  0
1989-02-09  BLS BellSouth Corporation   10.5937995910645    1.02371887326721    10.205209986368818  1
1989-02-09  BLY Bally Manufacturing Corporation 24.125  0.0336752484062539  22.7125 1
1989-02-09  BMET    Biomet Inc. 2.07406997680664    0.0 1.8774690270423904  1
1989-02-09  BMS Bemis Company, Inc. 6.46875 0.0333815440279137  6.159375    1
1989-02-09  BMY Bristol-Myers Squibb Company    11.6562004089355    1.21979276588525    11.280200068155915  1
1989-02-09  BNI Burlington Northern Inc.    8.29166984558106    0.0943037741233582  9.116664950052897   0
1989-02-09  BNL.1   Beneficial Corporation  23.0625 0.0514116221037734  22.50625    1
1989-02-09  BNSSA   BNS Holding Inc. Cl A   1712.5  0.00390742412562617 1732.5  0
1989-02-09  BOAT.   Boatmen's Bancshares Inc.   15.9375 0.0 15.402083333333334  1
1989-02-09  BOL Bausch & Lomb Inc.  23.0625 0.0690864662075295  21.835416666666667  1
1989-02-09  BRNOQ   Bruno's, Inc.   11.5    0.0 10.5375 1
1989-02-09  BSET    Bassett Furniture Industries, Inc.  20.9333000183105    0.0162415623077136  20.995553207397457  0
1989-02-09  BT.2    Bankers Trust Corporation   39.0    0.160023263334134   37.7    1
1989-02-09  BUD.2   Anheuser-Busch Companies Inc.   8.4375  0.478800185278591   8.090625    1
1989-02-09  BV.2    Blockbuster Entertainment Corporation   5.875   0.0 5.580208333333333   1
1989-02-09  BWY.1   Carter Hawley Hale Stores, Inc. 106.432998657227    0.0122959357274386  108.48949839274101  0
1989-02-09  C   Primerica Corp. 20.4167003631592    0.13856722834628    18.83332659403483   1
1989-02-09  CA  Computer Associates International, Inc. 5.46295976638794    0.17169934205776    5.1648139476776125  1
1989-02-09  CAG Conagra Brands, Inc.    6.83333015441895    0.12404529960465    6.78888799349467    1
1989-02-09  CAL Brown Group, Inc.   15.1111001968384    0.0297160772728691  14.801863352457678  1
1989-02-09  CAT Caterpillar Inc.    7.625   0.310358043053793   7.915104643503825   0
1989-02-09  CB.1    Chubb Corporation   8.0 0.136737092082188   7.539063294728597   1
1989-02-09  CBB.1   Roadway Services, Inc.  32.5    0.0638555756823075  30.904166666666665  1
1989-02-09  CBE Cooper Industries PLC Cl A  14.6875 0.16005277649102    14.225006612141934  1
1989-02-09  CBL.1   Corroon & Black Corporation 32.75   0.0283804074567535  31.683333333333334  1
1989-02-09  CBS.1   CBS Inc.    34.7000007629395    0.205833021690685   34.72416648864747   0
1989-02-09  CBS.2   Westinghouse Electric Corporation   27.9375 0.405990249330451   27.145833333333332  1
1989-02-09  CCB.2   Capital Cities/ABC Inc. 36.4500007629395    0.329143629477954   36.32791671752931   1
1989-02-09  CCK Crown Cork & Seal Company, Inc. 15.75   0.0619816582811502  16.126386642456055  0
1989-02-09  CCTYQ   Circuit City Stores, Inc.   5.1875  0.0470893436176551  4.939062976837159   1
1989-02-09  CEG Baltimore Gas and Electric Company  20.75   0.125449770549903   20.908329963684082  0
1989-02-09  CEM.2   First Mississippi Corporation   18.125  0.0179636490478221  17.679166666666667  1
1989-02-09  CFL.1   CoreStates Financial Corp.  21.375  0.0 20.364583333333332  1
1989-02-09  CGP.1   Coastal Corporation 12.0    0.122150222444316   11.650003369649253  1
1989-02-09  CHA.3   Champion International Corporation  34.0    0.162719460222096   32.9625 1
1989-02-09  CHRS.1  Charming Shoppes    8.375   0.0419875211279852  8.058333333333334   1
1989-02-09  CI  Cigna Corporation   5.9861102104187 0.212443665702546   5.610185368855794   1
1989-02-09  CIC.3   Continental Corporation 34.375  0.0929356545198307  33.541666666666664  1
1989-02-09  CKL Clark Equipment Company 35.0    0.0301528576533166  32.88333333333333   1
1989-02-09  CL  Colgate-Palmolive Company   2.91406011581421    0.161740631945346   2.8796873490015664  1
1989-02-09  CLX Clorox Company  8.40625 0.093453570890967   8.079166666666667   1
1989-02-09  CMB.1   Chase Manhattan Corporation 31.75   0.165914463503386   30.595833333333335  1
1989-02-09  CMCSA   Comcast Corporation Class A 4.30556011199951    0.0727171837349436  4.065740338961283   1
1989-02-09  CMCSK   Comcast Corporation 2.79629993438721    0.0 2.664197293917339   1
1989-02-09  CMI Cummins Inc.    8.23437976837158    0.0343380573052872  8.061458333333333   1
1989-02-09  CNA CNA Financial Corporation   19.0573997497559    0.183978027660471   19.303053601582846  0
1989-02-09  CNG Consolidated Natural Gas Company    39.75   0.16463220292242    40.25416666666667   0
1989-02-09  CNP Houston Industries Inc. 14.0    0.176851809165661   14.122916666666667  0
1989-02-09  CNW CNF, Inc.   35.5    0.0623035079736531  34.2    1
1989-02-09  COP Phillips Petroleum Company  10.4375 0.255480612798307   10.395833333333334  1
1989-02-09  COST    Price Costco Inc.   3.0 0.0 2.888193988800049   1
1989-02-09  CPB Campbell Soup Company   7.6875  0.199902975031127   7.873958333333333   0
1989-02-09  CPQ.2   Compaq Computer Corporation 2.45000004768372    0.144168468161348   2.2050003528594972  1
1989-02-09  CR  Crane Co.   7.70370006561279    0.0275577572916504  7.181481997172038   1
1989-02-09  CRR.3   Conrail Inc.    18.25   0.125474684243604   17.752083333333335  1
1989-02-09  CSR.1   Central and South West Corporation  15.5    0.146397574691651   15.879166666666666  0
1989-02-09  CSX CSX Corporation 2.76042008399963    0.162611702393541   2.7236099720001237  1
1989-02-09  CTB Cooper Tire & Rubber Company    6.46875 0.0 5.948958333333334   1
1989-02-09  CTCO.1  Cross & Trecker Corporation 14.75   0.00916415631506231 15.25   0
1989-02-09  CTX Centex Corp.    3.57811999320984    0.0214711484180796  3.609373998641968   0
1989-02-09  CUE.1   Quantum Chemical Corporation    56.785099029541 0.0723993908092653  66.92875633239748   0
1989-02-09  CVGYQ   Ogden Corporation   29.375  0.0587044902461742  30.116666666666667  0
1989-02-09  CVN.3   C&S Sovran Corporation  26.625  0.0 25.366666666666667  1
1989-02-09  CVS Melville Corporation    10.0312004089355    0.21934796923864    9.745833333333335   1
1989-02-09  CVX Chevron Corporation 12.1562004089355    0.834571703953511   12.075009918212901  1
1989-02-09  CYM.1   Cyprus Amax Minerals Company    26.0832996368408    0.0504931397856913  24.044436581929524  1
1989-02-09  CYR.1   Cray Research Inc.  61.125  0.0896891120382095  61.270833333333336  0
1989-02-09  D   Dominion Energy Inc 13.7917003631592    0.20573291393175    14.061109987894698  0
1989-02-09  DALRQ   Delta Air Lines Inc.    27.9375 0.141985861046245   26.491666666666667  1
1989-02-09  DCNAQ   Dana Corp.  19.8125 0.0808008517680322  19.704166666666666  1
1989-02-09  DD  E. I. du Pont de Nemours and Company    16.4792003631592    1.1602971239933 15.795833333333329  1
1989-02-09  DDS Dillard Department Stores, Inc. 15.0832996368408    0.0794672513020937  14.32639338175456   1
1989-02-09  DE  Deere & Company 7.79166984558106    0.177135710513493   7.876388676961264   0
1989-02-09  DEC Digital Equipment Corporation   114.375 0.697395529759543   107.11666666666666  1
1989-02-09  DGN.    Data General Corporation    18.0    0.0263519163363923  18.216666666666665  0
1989-02-09  DI. Dresser Industries Inc. 16.8125 0.114167616801963   15.575  1
1989-02-09  DIGI.1  DSC Communications Corporation  4.0 0.0157929480577047  3.7729166666666667  1
1989-02-09  DIS Walt Disney Company 6.23958015441895    0.505436414689496   5.880208969116213   1
1989-02-09  DJ  Dow Jones & Company Inc.    32.625  0.165044611593755   31.504166666666666  1
1989-02-09  DLX Deluxe Corporation  26.5    0.113529222786301   25.866666666666667  1
1989-02-09  DOV Dover Corporation   7.3125  0.0923147899830392  7.4375  0
1989-02-09  DOW2    Union Carbide Corporation   29.25   0.204388895071749   27.408333333333335  1
1989-02-09  DTE The Detroit Edison Company  18.125  0.133505700125553   17.908333333333335  1
1989-02-09  DUK Duke Energy Corporation 34.0312004089356    0.230548718887156   34.50937334696453   0
1989-02-09  DWDP    Dow Chemical Co.    21.7777996063232    0.902358294717968   20.467589823404957  1
1989-02-09  DXC Computer Sciences Corporation   8.77083015441895    0.0418677886024356  8.272222010294598   1
1989-02-09  DYHGQ   Datapoint Corp. 4.5 0.00227771905955565 4.4375  1
1989-02-09  E.2 Transco Energy Company  38.5    0.0 36.8625 1
1989-02-09  ECH.1   Echlin Inc. 17.0    0.0475481171477016  16.725  1
1989-02-09  ECL Ecolab Inc. 3.45311999320984    0.0380576822723671  3.3270826657613117  1
1989-02-09  ECO.2   Echo Bay Mines Ltd. 15.75   0.0 14.6375 1
1989-02-09  ED  Consolidated Edison Company of New York, Inc.   22.6875 0.259662110758227   23.304166666666667  0
1989-02-09  EFU.1   Eastern Enterprises 29.0    0.0337685686188658  29.0    0
1989-02-09  EIX SCEcorp 16.3125 0.357574028780957   16.358333333333334  0
1989-02-09  EKDKQ   Eastman Kodak Company   47.75   0.777163681004211   46.45   1
1989-02-09  EMR Emerson Electric Co.    7.78125 0.347756266109072   7.752083333333333   1
1989-02-09  ENRNQ   Enron Corp. 4.57812023162842    0.0922954599645256  4.597395038604736   0
1989-02-09  ESY.1   E-Systems Inc.  30.75   0.047831761505683   30.254166666666666  1
1989-02-09  ETN Eaton Corp. 7.32812023162842    0.108732684550305   7.178645356496175   1
1989-02-09  ETR Entergy Corporation 16.375  0.168068422297693   15.975  1
1989-02-09  EXC Philadelphia Electric Company   10.4375 0.219571201035979   10.1375 1
```

Comment: can you post the dataframe

Comment: give some sample data

Comment: groupby sets the date column to one of the index levels, and `.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)` drops that index level, removing the `drop=True` might fix your issue.

Comment: @Swier thanks. I'm getting ValueError: cannot insert Date, already exists. Tried to delete both in reset_index but still returns nans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the  `'Date'` from the [  ], you are already grouping by it. And don't drop the index, `Date` is your new index in your returning dataframe and you want to keep it

```
target_df_count_total = data_frame.groupby('Date')['Price above Mean'].count().reset_index(level=0)
```